# How does one submit an article "informally"?

Tags: publications, etiquette

Although I have read a lot in my area of interest (plant taxonomy and botanical nomenclature), in am no academic of it, having only a Bachelor of Translation degree.

It has taken me two years of waffling back and forth before I worked up the courage to write up a quick note (something not entirely dissimilar to [this](http://www.phytoneuron.net/PhytoN-Dermatophyllum.pdf) in nature, mostly bibliographical, but necessary nonetheless) which I'd like to submit to [*Phytoneuron*](http://www.phytoneuron.net/phytoneuronINFO.htm). I call it "informal" because it is an independent, one-man journal with a relatively unelaborated review process where one sends the prospective article straight to the editor.

However, I have NO idea what sort of language one in my situation can be expected to address to a journal editor. That I am diagnosed with Asperger's Syndrome and have been told before my writing can be overly formal to comical or insulting degrees at times is not helping my crushing nervosity about the whole thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could write something like the following. Short and sweet.

---

To the editor,

Please find attached an article for consideration for publication in the journal Phytoneuron.  I assert that this is an original contribution and it has not been submitted for consideration elsewhere.
Could you please acknowledge receipt of this submission?

Best regards,
**Your name**
**Your Affiliation**

**Title of Article**
**Authors**

Abstract

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas odio non mi mattis rhoncus. Vivamus ultrices urna a ante tristique pellentesque. Nam tincidunt lacus a mi sollicitudin tincidunt. Curabitur malesuada, quam sit amet iaculis lobortis, enim lacus commodo turpis, nec elementum mauris libero ac enim. Quisque justo mauris, eleifend id ornare vel, luctus eget tellus. Etiam auctor ultrices tincidunt. Curabitur diam nulla, aliquam nec gravida a, consequat non nulla. Cras viverra massa id felis blandit gravida. Pellentesque enim mi, convallis vitae ornare quis, ornare sit amet dolor. Pellentesque velit urna, feugiat non tincidunt in, sollicitudin sed purus. Phasellus laoreet ligula nec odio mattis fringilla. Fusce sed arcu mi. Pellentesque dictum erat sit amet sapien pharetra porta.